# What is the correct documentation for Selenium By.ByClassName class

Tags: api, selenium, documentation

I found to links of api document and want to understand who is more relevant today:

[first source](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.1/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByClassName.html)

[Second source](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByClassName.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [first link](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.1/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByClassName.html) is the from the `spring-core` within [springframework](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-core/latest/index.html) which needs updation.

Where as the [second link](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByClassName.html) is the official JavaDocs from SeleniumHQ and the most updated.